# If and elif statements not working/not being recognised by python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to create a little Rock paper scissors game as I am a beginner but I am having issues with my if and elif statements.

```py
import random
player_score = 0
computer_score = 0
options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

def player_choice():
    input('Rock, Paper or Scissors? ')
    return player_choice
def computer_choice():
    print(random.choice(options))
    return computer_choice

ps = print('player score: ', player_score)
cs = print('computer_score: ',computer_score)

while player_score or computer_score < 10:
    player_choice()
    computer_choice()

if player_choice == 'rock' and computer_choice == 'rock':
        print('Tie')
elif player_choice == 'rock' and computer_choice == 'paper':
        print('Computer wins')
        computer_score = computer_score + 1
        print(ps)
        print(cs)
elif player_choice == 'rock' and computer_choice == 'scissors':
        print('You win')
        player_score = player_score + 1
        print(ps)
        print(cs)
```

It seems as though the entire if/ elif block is ignored and nothing prints or is incremented. No error pops up, it is just simply ignored.

Comment: player_choice = player_choice()
computer_choice = computer_choice() and you'll probably want to tab your if statement in so that it lies beneath your while statement

Comment: Did you mean to indent the `if ... else` statements under the `while` loop?

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of problems with your code, and I am going to try and address all of them.

The first one has to do with the naming of your variables. You name your functions `computer_choice` and `player_choice`, and then check if they equal `"rock"` or other strings. This is only going to return False because `computer_choice` is a function, not a string. I would recommend changing the names of your functions to `get_computer_choice()` and `get_player_choice()`

Secondly, `ps = print('player score: ', player_score)`. I don't know what you are trying to do there. `ps` will be `None`, because `print()` doesn't return anything.

Third, your functions return *themselves*.

```py
def my_func():
    return my_func
```

Will return a function. What you want to do for both of your choice functions is this:

```py
def get_player_choice():
    player_choice = input('Rock, Paper or Scissors? ')
    return player_choice

def get_computer_choice():
    computer_choice = random.choice(options) # Set computer_choice to computers choice
    print(computer_choice)
    return computer_choice
```

Fourth, under your while loop, you are calling the functions, but aren't doing anything with the returns. Change

```py
while player_score or computer_score < 10:
    player_choice()
    computer_choice()
```

to

```py
while player_score or computer_score < 10:
    player_choice = get_player_choice()
    computer_choice = get_computer_choice()
```

Finally, the `if ... else` statements need to be indented under the while loop, otherwise they never get executed.

Comment: Good answer, I'll upvote if you add indenting the if statements under the while loop.

Comment: @CodingClown lol done. I didn't include it originally because I wasn't sure If that was just a mistake he made when transferring it to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the 13th line of your code. I couldn't understand what `ps = print(...)` means.

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues with your code.

```
def player_choice():
    input('Rock, Paper or Scissors? ')
    return player_choice
```

player_choice is not initialised. Input takes the user input, but the result is not stored anywhere.

```
def get_player_choice():
    choice = input("Rock, Paper or Scissors? ")
    return choice
```

Same procedure for `computer_choice`.

Then there is:

```
ps = print('player score: ', player_score)
cs = print('computer_score: ',computer_score)
```

I assume you tried to construct a string containing the scores. I suggest

```
def print_score():
    print('player score: ', player_score)
    print('computer_score: ',computer_score)
```

instead. You can then call the function whenever you want to see the score.

And finally, the indent was not right for the if-else statements. It should have been in the while loop. Now it just asks the user for input and generates a choice for the computer in an endless loop.

Here are all changes I suggested combined:

```
import random
player_score = 0
computer_score = 0
options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

def get_player_choice():
    player_choice= input('Rock, Paper or Scissors? ')
    return player_choice
def get_computer_choice():
    computer_choice = random.choice(options)
    print(computer_choice)
    return computer_choice

def print_score():
    print('player score: ', player_score)
    print('computer_score: ',computer_score)

while player_score < 10  and computer_score < 10:
    player_choice = get_player_choice()
    computer_choice = get_computer_choice()

    if player_choice == 'rock' and  computer_choice == 'rock':
        print('Tie')
    elif player_choice == 'rock' and computer_choice == 'paper':
        print('Computer wins')
        computer_score = computer_score + 1
        print_score()
    elif player_choice == 'rock' and computer_choice == 'scissors':
        print('You win')
        player_score = player_score + 1
        print_score()
```

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

> **1.** I changed the name of your functions to avoid a later error when calling them.

> **2.** As suggested in another answers you must pass a variable to store the result from the functions.

> **3.** It was missing indentation

> **4.** Some of your conditions were not right. Such as the `while` condition: if ((player_score<10) **or** (computer_score < 10)), even if someone reaches the score of 10, the game will keep going. We don't want that, so it must be the `and` condition.

Here is the solution:

```
import random

player_score = 0
computer_score = 0

options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

def choice_player():
    
    result_player = str((input('rock, paper or scissors? ')))
    return (result_player)

def choice_computer():
    result_computer = random.choice(options)
    return (result_computer)


#---------------------------------------------
ps = print('player score: ', player_score)
cs = print('computer_score: ',computer_score)

while ((player_score<10) and (computer_score < 10)):
    
    player_choice = choice_player()
    computer_choice = choice_computer()

    if ((player_choice == 'rock') and (computer_choice == 'rock')):
        print('Tie')
    elif ((player_choice == 'rock') and (computer_choice == 'paper')):
        print('Computer wins')
        computer_score = computer_score + 1
        print('player score: ', player_score)
        print('computer_score: ',computer_score)
    elif ((player_choice == 'rock') and (computer_choice == 'scissors')):
        print('You win')
        player_score = player_score + 1
        print('player score: ', player_score)
        print('computer_score: ',computer_score)
```